# Laravel how to check if value exists in Form::select before assigning it?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a predefined Laravels `Form::select` with multiple values.

My problem is that users can import data that doesn't exist in my predefined list. So what I'm looking for here is to either check first if the value exists in the list and if it doesn't change it to a different value (Is it possible to check the list directly or do I have to create another array again to use for checking),

OR if it's possible when assigning the value in `Form::select` and it doesn't exist in the list assign another value to it.

Comment: i think you can check like if it is in_array($value,$values) then render your select options each time they import data into list

Comment: I was hoping that laravel has some builtin functions so that I won't have to do it that way.

Comment: can you please provide us some of the error or code snippet for more clarification ?

Comment: There is no error. I just want to know if Laravel is capable of such a feat. Because if not then I'll just have to manually check the value by creating an array for my dropdown list.